# Recyclerview onScrolled called when keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview in activity A which is used to play videos automatically on scroll. So i have added onScrollListener to the recyclerview of activity A. Everything work fine but

1. I launch another activity B from activity A
2. keyboard appears on activity B
3. onScroll method of recyclerview of activity A get called.

As a result video start playing on activity A which is in the background. Any idea, how to stop this?

Below are the code for both activities.

Activity A

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ExoVideosAdapter exoVideosAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn=findViewById(R.id.btnB);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondActivity.class));
        }
    });
    exoVideosAdapter=new ExoVideosAdapter();
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            Log.d("rvA","onScrollStateChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            Log.d("rvA","onScrolled");
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(exoVideosAdapter);
}
```

}

Activity B just have a edittext

```
public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}}
```

Comment: post your code here for activity a and b class

Comment: Why down vote guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this strange behavior is using translucent theme for your app. Once i removed translucent tag it stopped calling onScrollListener of recyclerview of background activity.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points which you can take care of:

1. Stop your `onScrollListener` while calling `intent` to another Activity B.
2. If you do not want to maintain backward compatibility you can `finish` your Activity A while calling Intent for Activity B.
3. `Stop` you processes like playing videos when `Activity A goes in background` i.e `onPause` and `onStop`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, i am managing onScrollListener during onPause and onResume of activity A as a temporary solution right now. But this behavior is very weird.

Comment: @jatinrana start your video playing in onStart() of your activity and stop it on onPause() and onStop() seems a bit quite sufficient.

Comment: Thanks but that is just a workaround. The real reason for this behavior is using translucent theme for your app. Once i removed translucent theme everything work normal.